# How does this ORDER BY question makes sense?

Tags: oracle

How is the first option correct if the second option is incorrect. What source can I use to understand more about how data types effect the ORDER BY functions?

[image]

Comment: Please Note That basic SQL questions are not appropriate for dba.stackexchange https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

The key bit of information is that the data type is character. '4' > '100'

Comment: I don't understand the theory behind it. But I'll just assume that in regards of data size, characters data type is the opposite of numbers? So  '4' > '5' if both data types are characters. But '4' < '5' if both data types are numbers. Correct?

Comment: No. '4' < '5' and also '40' < '5'. They’re strings so you treat them like strings. Eg 'Andy' < 'Ben’ because 'A’ < 'B’, doesn’t matter that there’s an 'n’ after the 'A'

Comment: Understood. Thank you Sir

Comment: It's `'40' < '5'` but `40 > 5` (without quotes). Because with quotes they are strings (or VARCHAR2 in Oracle) and without quotes they are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> If the Data Type is numeric, the value 4 will appear before the value 100.

Sorting numbers [in descending order], everything works as you would *expect*:

```
select n 
from table 
order by n desc ; 

n 
--- 
100 
 75 
 50 
 25 
 10 
  4
```

> If the Data Type is character the value 4 will appear before the value 100.

Sorting *character* data [in descending order], things start to go awry which, I suspect, is the whole point of this question:

```
select n 
from table 1 
order by n desc ;
 
n
---
'75' 
'50' 
'4' 
'25' 
'100' 
'10'
```

This is why you **must** store your data in fields on the correct Data Type.